# Cache Manifest: What is the prefer-online setting?

Tags: html, application-cache, cache-manifest

I've been looking for a way to cache pages for use only when the user is offline, otherwise download the pages normally. However, once a cache manifest is detected, the browser will only load from those cached pages.

My search landed me on http://whatwg.org. The section about [Writing Cache Manifests](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/offline.html#writing-cache-manifests) caught my eye. Here's an excerpt:

> **A section header**
>
> Section headers change the current section. There are four possible section headers:
>
> ```
> CACHE:
>     Switches to the explicit section. 
> FALLBACK:
>     Switches to the fallback section. 
> NETWORK:
>     Switches to the online whitelist section. 
> SETTINGS:
>     Switches to the settings section.
> ```

The first three are well known, but I hadn't heard of the last section header, `SETTINGS:`. The documentation continues to say this:

> Currently only one **setting** is defined:
>
> **The cache mode setting**
>
> This consists of the string "`prefer-online`". It sets the cache mode to prefer-online. (The cache mode defaults to fast.)

This made me wonder if the `prefer-online` setting was exactly what I was looking for. I was hoping that this setting would tell the browser that it should only load the cached pages if the setting was set to `fast`, otherwise download the pages if the user is online.

Unfortunately, I can't find any additional information or explanation about this. Has anyone come across any information about the `prefer-online` setting? Or about the `SETTINGS:` section in general?

Comment: Which browsers did you test with the `prefer-online`setting? For me it worked well with Firefox 14.0.1 and Opera 12.00 but Chrome 21.0.1180.75 and Androids (API Level 13 - emulator) native browser and WebView seems to ignore it.

Comment: I'm not sure of the versions, I didn't write them down at the time, but I tried it with Chrome and Firefox. I'm glad it's working in newer versions, though.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`prefer-online` will go to the server if there is a connection, even if the file is cached. If there is no connection it will use the cache.

`fast` will use the offline version, even if there is a connection.

Although you can set these preferences, the user agent can still decide what it thinks is best.

Comment: So you're **believing** just exactly what was mentioned in the question? nice "answer"...

Comment: @MarvinEmilBrach: Unless he's actually wrong that's still a valid answer though. Besides that, the NAA flag is not for *wrong* answers.

Comment: I have removed the emotive word "believe" from the answer. I hope the new version is more assertive, as it is correct.

Comment: This is true for MASTER entities onnly, not for any others.

Comment: @SteveFenton can you include a link that describe setting section

Comment: How do you set it in the SETTINGS: section? Is there a declaration and then the setting, or do you just type

SETTINGS:
prefer-online