# HTML5 manifest: Can I use prefer-online?

Tags: html

I am trying to implement web application that gets data from the server when it is online and falls back to the last retrieved data when it is offline. I am using an HTML 5 manifest. I have read about the following setting:

SETTINGS:
prefer-online

With this in the manifest, I expect so see the site request data from the server when I am online.

However, none of the browsers I am using, (Internet Explorer 11, Chrome 35 and Firefox 19)  request data from the browser in this circumstance.

I am wondering if this "prefer-online" feature is implemented in the browsers I am using.

Has anyone else used this feature successfully? Have I misunderstood how it should work? Is it implemented in these browsers?

Comment: Maybe you will find what you seek here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11263765/cache-manifest-what-is-the-prefer-online-setting

Comment: Thanks, I saw that answer but it doesn't seem to reflect my experience. I was wondering if anyone has used prefer-online and had it working as I describe?